# Adding CKEditor Plugins to Wygwam 4.0.9 in EE3

Tags: wygwam, ee3, ckeditor

I'm attempting to add a **CKEditor plugin** to **Wygwam 4.0.9** in **EE3**, but the documentation I found in [pixelandtonic](https://docs.pixelandtonic.com/wygwam/developers/ckeditor_plugins.html) and [wygwam docs](https://eeharbor.com/wygwam/documentation/ckeditor_plugins) showing wrong upload folders.

There is no such folders as `themes/third_party/` and `system/expressionengine/third_party/` .

Please confirm the exact folder names where I will upload the PHP files.

Answer (score 1):

In **EE3** :

Theme third-party folder path is as follow:
`themes/user/`

System third-party folder path is as follow:
`system/user/addons/`

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded smiley plugin to themes/user/smiley and created following ext.smiley.php and uploaded to system/user/addons/smiley, but the plugin is not appearing.

```
<?php if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class smiley_ext
{
var $name           = 'smiley';
var $version        = '1.0';
var $description    = '';
var $docs_url       = 'http://ckeditor.com/';
var $settings_exist = 'n';

private $_hooks = array(
    'wygwam_config',
    'wygwam_tb_groups',
);

private static $_included_resources = FALSE;

public function activate_extension()
{
    foreach ($this->_hooks as $hook)
    {
        ee()->db->insert('extensions', array(
            'class'    => get_class($this),
            'method'   => $hook,
            'hook'     => $hook,
            'settings' => '',
            'priority' => 10,
            'version'  => $this->version,
            'enabled'  => 'y'
        ));
    }
}

public function update_extension($current = NULL)
{
    return FALSE;
}

public function disable_extension()
{
    ee()->db->where('class', get_class($this))->delete('extensions');
}


public function wygwam_config($config, $settings)
{
    if (($last_call = ee()->extensions->last_call) !== FALSE)
    {
        $config = $last_call;
    }

    // Check if our toolbar button has been added
    $include_btn = FALSE;

    foreach ($config['toolbar'] as $tbgroup)
    {
        if (in_array('MyPlugin', $tbgroup))
        {
            $include_btn = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($include_btn)
    {
        // Add our plugin to CKEditor
        if (!empty($config['extraPlugins']))
        {
            $config['extraPlugins'] .= ',';
        }

        $config['extraPlugins'] .= 'myplugin';

        $this->_include_resources();
    }

    return $config;
}

private function _include_resources()
{
    // Is this the first time we've been called?
    if (!self::$_included_resources)
    {
        // Tell CKEditor where to find our plugin
        $plugin_url = URL_THIRD_THEMES.'smiley/myplugin/';
        ee()->cp->add_to_foot('<script type="text/javascript">CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal("myplugin", "'.$plugin_url.'");</script>');

        // Don't do that again
        self::$_included_resources = TRUE;
    }
}

public function wygwam_tb_groups($tb_groups)
{
    if (($last_call = ee()->extensions->last_call) !== FALSE)
    {
        $tb_groups = $last_call;
    }

    $tb_groups[] = array('MyPlugin');

    // Is this the toolbar editor?
    if (ee()->input->get('M') == 'show_module_cp')
    {
        // Give our toolbar button an icon
        $icon_url = URL_THIRD_THEMES.'smiley/myplugin/icons/smiley.png';
        ee()->cp->add_to_head('<style type="text/css">.cke_button__myplugin_icon { background-image: url('.$icon_url.'); }</style>');
    }

    return $tb_groups;
}

}
```

Comment: Have you created `addon.setup.php` file ? It is required for ee3 addons.

Comment: Also you need to replace `myplugin` with `smiley`.

Comment: and the first letter of class name should be capital "Smiley_ext"